# Conditional formatting on Duplicates using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, filter, conditional-formatting, pandas-styles

I have a dataFrame with 6 columns. And I want to do conditional formatting on two columns of them. So my dataFrame looks like this

[image]

And I want to highlight duplicate values from College and College_F2 columns.
After which my dataframe will look like this

[image]

The code written for this looks like this:

```py
dataFrame_file = pd.read_excel(util.comcastFile2Path(), sheet_name='Sheet1')

def dummy_color(x):
    c1 = 'background-color:red'
    c2 = ''
    cond = dataFrame_file.stack().duplicated(keep=False).unstack()
    df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.where(cond, c1, c2), columns=x.columns, index=x.index)
    return df1

dataFrame_file.style.apply(dummy_color,axis=None,subset=['College', 'College_F2']).to_excel(util.comcastFile2Path)
```

And the error this code is giving to me is

```
ValueError: Shape of passed values is (6, 6), indices imply (6, 2)
```

IDE that I am using is PyCharm.
How to resolve this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please provide (at least your initial) dataframe via `df.head().to_dict()`

Comment: @rpanai `dataFrame_file = pd.read_excel(util.comcastFile2Path(), sheet_name='Sheet1')` This is how I am providing the dataFrame.

Answer (score 2):

In solution is necessary working with all DataFrame, so omited `subset` parameter and in `cond` filtered columns for check duplicates and also added [`DataFrame.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) for filling `False` to all another columns:

```
def dummy_color(x):
    c1 = 'background-color:red'
    c2 = ''
    cond = (x[['College', 'College_F2']].stack()
                                        .duplicated(keep=False)
                                        .unstack()
                                        .reindex(x.columns, axis=1, fill_value=False))
    df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.where(cond, c1, c2), columns=x.columns, index=x.index)
    return df1

dataFrame_file.style.apply(dummy_color,axis=None).to_excel(util.comcastFile2Path)
```

Like @anky_91 mentioned simplier is use subset parameter with `x` for `cond` variable, I think reason is `x` variable are only columns filtered by `subset` list:

```
def dummy_color(x):
    c1 = 'background-color:red'
    c2 = ''
    cond = x.stack().duplicated(keep=False).unstack()
    df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.where(cond, c1, c2), columns=x.columns, index=x.index)
    return df1

dataFrame_file.style.apply(dummy_color,axis=None, subset=['College', 'College_F2']).to_excel(util.comcastFile2Path)
```

Comment: interesting , wonder why the solution didnot work , only except the `cond` line where `dataFrame_file` need to be replaced by `x`  and it works for me , but this is a nice alternative :)

Answer (score 0):

```py
def dummy_color(x):
    color = 'red' if (len(dataFrame_file[dataFrame_file['College'] == x]) + len(dataFrame_file[dataFrame_file['College_F2'] == x])) > 1 else ''
    return 'background-color: %s' % color

dataFrame_file.style.applymap(dummy_color, subset=['College', 'College_F2']).to_excel(util.comcastFile2Path)
```